# Accelerating expansion of universe - entire universe a non-inertial frame of reference?

Tags: special-relativity, acceleration, space-expansion, inertial-frames

If the expansion of the universe is accelerating, doesn't that mean that the entire universe is a non-inertial frame of reference? And if so, what implications does this have (if any)?

Comment: Frame of reference should be defined at single point, or you palling to shrink whole universe to a point?, even so being our earth is not inertial frame of reference, Astronomers includes that in there measures, and it's not enough to describe the expansion.

Comment: Note: In GR, generally there cannot be any global inertial frame of references, only local ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The expansion of the universe and the accelerated expansion is simply a scale factor change, not any kind of motion at all. For there to be a real acceleration there would have to be a preferred direction to the acceleration.  The universe is isotropic so there is no direction for the acceleration, the scale factor change simply increases the distance between any pair of points.